# Using $in and $and on MONGODB is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using MONGOHQ and NODE.JS to make an application, I would really like the help of someone because I have a big problem, I tried everything and look everywhere, so this is my last option.

I have this query on a node JS post:

```
{ propertyId: '53f4f097f28c16cf87a15664' }
```

This query is being used here :

```
db.collection('animal').find(req.body.query).toArray(function (err, animals) {
      res.send(
           (err === null) ? { status: 'ok', result: animals } : { status: err }
      );
 });
```

And its working FINE !

**Now the problem :**

What I want is to add another query to the find, without modifying the req.body.query.

What I have is a list of _id (not ObjectIds), called myArray, and it's like :

```
[ '12312123' , '78787878' ]
```

So I am doing this :

```
db.collection('animal').find({ $and : [ req.body.query, { '​_id' : { $in : myArray} } ] }).toArray(function (err, animals) {
       res.send(
             (err === null) ? { status: 'ok', result: animals } : { status: err }
       );
});
```

And its giving me an empty list.

But instead, if I do the same query on mongohq like :

```
find({​$and : [ { propertyId: '53f4f097f28c16cf87a15664' }, { '​_id' : { $in :['12312123', '78787878']} } ] })
```

Its giving me a list with 1 element that matches the criteria:

```
{
  _id: "12312123",
  propertyId: "53f4f097f28c16cf87a15664",
  active: "true"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?
I would be glad to hear !

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Is there some reason it wouldn't work to just make a copy of the `req.body.query` object and then adding your other conditions to that copied object (instead of using `$and`)?

Comment: Good idea, how would you do that ?

Comment: What is `req.body.query`? Can you print it out? If it's really the same query, it should return the same result.

Comment: @MichaelDiego I added an answer on how to do it.

Comment: Its { propertyId: '53f4f097f28c16cf87a15664' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify why you don't want to modify `req.body.query`, but there could be many reasons for that, so here's how you could make a copy of it before modifying it, that way you don't even need to bother with `$and`:

```
var query = req.body.query;
//make a copy of the query object
var queryCopy = {};
for (var i in query) {
    queryCopy[i] = query[i];
}

//add your additional conditions
queryCopy._id: { $in : myArray} };

var result = db.collection('animal').find(queryCopy);
//result.toArray(...)
```

Note that this approach only creates a shallow copy of the object, which is fine in this case because you're not modifying any nested objects or arrays. If you want you could add a function for creating shallow copies, here's one you could use (I prefer to use `Object.keys()` for this generic function instead of the `var i in...` approach above because it doesn't unnecessarily copy prototype properties [although sometimes you might want that] but it doesn't make a difference in your case.)

```
function shallowCopy(obj) {
    var copy = {},
        keys = Object.keys(obj),
        len = keys.length;

    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        copy[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

If you DO need to create a deep copy of an object because you want to modify nested objects and arrays without affecting the original object, then you'll need to use a function specifically designed for that purpose, since Javascript doesn't provide a native function to do that. Here's a deep copy function (from my answer to a question about that) - use the more robust version since that has proper support for arrays, regular expressions, and dates:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333781/560114

Comment: Thanks mate ! It really helped me for my work ! I owe you one

Little correction for viewers:

var query = req.body.query;
//make a copy of the query object
var queryCopy = {};

for (var i in query) {
    queryCopy[i] = query[i];
}

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I edited it into my answer. BTW since you found my answer helpful, you might consider upvoting it (the usual practice on SO is to both accept and upvote), but thanks for accepting it, that's the main thing :) This is just FYI I'm not actually that obsessed with my number of points haha.

Comment: Hahaha no problem mate, I tried to do it, but it says that I need at least 15 reputation to vote... Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, I forgot about that part. Cheers :)